# sqlite3: How to use SELECT + WHERE to search a random row?

Tags: python, sqlite

Eg. In the Table1 there is a column ColName, some of the items in ColName are "Mike".

The code to search one of the them:

```
searchString = " SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ColName = 'Mike' "
cur.execute(searchString).fetchone()
```

**The Problem:** The code above allways gives me the first row, where "Mike" in ColName appears.

I actually want, by everytime running the sqlite code, to get a `random` search result from the column ColName, whose value is "Mike". How could I change the code?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a random value, then you need to iterate over `cur.execute(searchString)` for some random amount, then extract the column(s).

`fetchone()` always returns the top result

The alternative includes trying to randomly sort the query results in SQL

Comment: Just use `ORDER BY RAND()`

Comment: Sure. I'm not super familiar with the sqlite functions